# Dockerfile 'FROM' command not executing a line

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am building a Dockerfile however when I execute `docker build` , it returns an error:

```
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 7: FROM requires either one or three arguments
```

My line 7 command is:

`FROM nvidia-docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-gpu`

I am a bit confused as to why this command does not work because I use this command in bash to build the docker that I require (without the `FROM` command obviously).

NOTE: I want to build an image of this `nvidia-docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-gpu` AND have some other stuff on top of that image which I have included in the subsequent lines of the Dockerfile.

Comment: Why do you think it should work? Do you mean RUN instead of FROM? But then you would start docker inside docker ...

Comment: I don't think that's how Dockerfiles work. Dockerfiles are recipes for containers, having `run` in there doesn't make sense. Dockerfiles do allow `RUN` but it's to execute a command as part of the build process. This is different from `docker run` which is to start a container. I'd recommend having a look through the docs and checking out some Dockerfile examples

Comment: Dockerfiles are for building new images... _I think_ what you need is just a script that executes that command

Comment: I do not want to start a docker within a docker. I want to build an image of this `nvidia-docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-gpu` AND some other stuff in that image which I have in the subsequent lines of the Dockerfile. I want an image that has the nvidia docker as well as other stuff on top of it.

Comment: Please include your full Dockerfile. With this on line 7, I suspect you are trying to create an accidental multi-stage build without an understanding of that that is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with the usage of nvidia-docker:

> nvidia-docker is essentially a wrapper around the docker command that
>   transparently provisions a container with the necessary components to
>   execute code on the GPU. It is only absolutely necessary when using
>   nvidia-docker run to execute a container that uses GPUs.

So what you are trying to do is run a command inside a Dockerfile.

I think that what you want to do is something like:

```
FROM gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-gpu
...
```

As you see, the Dockerfile contains no reference to nvidia wrapper as it will be used to run the container, not to build the image.

And then build and run the image with the nvidia wrapper:

```
docker build -t tensorflow .
nvidia-docker run -it tensorflow
```

Comment: Where would I run the command `nvidia-docker run -it tensorflow`? In the dockerfile I have some commands that executes code on the GPU.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, hope the issue is solved. In case it isn't: `nvidia-docker` is a command to be used on a terminal or similar. Probably wherever you run the `docker build` command.

Answer (score 1):

The `FROM` keyword is used like this:

```
FROM ImageName
```

and `nvidia-docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-gpu` is not an image name. You should find an image (name) you want to start from, and put it in there. What you have there is a command.

see the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

```
FROM <image> [AS <name>]
Or

FROM <image>[:<tag>] [AS <name>]
Or

FROM <image>[@<digest>] [AS <name>]
```